# iOS Mantle Overcoat mapping array of entity ID

Tags: ios, json, github-mantle

I am using Overcoat and Mantle.

Our JSON from our REST server returns something like:

```
{
    results:[{
            id: 123,
            eventName: @"ABC"
            ...
            private_users: [50, 37, 24]
        },{
            id: 124,
            eventName: @"DEF"
            ...
            private_users: [40, 27, 14]
        },{
            id: 125,
            eventName: @"GHI"
            ...
            private_users: [60, 47, 34]
        },
    ]
}
```

So in this case, we have an Event entity and each event entity has a property called "private_users" which is an array of userID for each User entity.

If the above JSON had private_users containing an array of User entity instead of userID, I would already be able to map it using Mantle and Overcoat but the problem I am facing is, it's an array of userID.

I want to know how I can map/transform those userID in the private_users property using Mantle and Overcoat.

I am initially trying:

```
+(NSValueTransformer *)privateGroupsJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^NSArray *(NSArray *arrUserID) {

        // create new User entities and assign each a userID from arrUserID ?

    }];
}
```

Is that the right way to do it?

**How do you normally store an array of integers in Mantle?**

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

OK, seems like just declaring a NSArray *userIDs and setting the entity property in the xcdatamodel file type to Transformable is all I had to do.